# Executable .R file not running, path ignored

Tags: r, rscript

I'm trying to make `helloworld.R` run. I have given it executable rights and have added `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` at the top of the file. (I have also attempted `#!/usr/bin/en Rscript`). It is a relatively simple file:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

x <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x = x)
write.csv(df, "sim_data.csv")
```

However, any attempt to run the file has been met with the following error

```
ARGUMENT '/home/path/to/file/helloworld.R' __ignored__

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

(...)
```

Surprisingly, renaming the file to `helloworld.py` lets it run just fine (and outputs `sim_data.csv` with its expected content), but this seems hacky, so I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Comment: This behavior would occur if the executable were R, rather than Rscript; is /usr/bin/Rscript actually a distinct executable, or a manually created link to R?

Comment: @MartinMorgan I have assumed they were the same thing. I don't think I have made any manual configurations after simply installing R, so it's likely that it's a distinct executable.

Comment: please show the filesystem attributes of the file _and_ how you're calling it on the command line

Comment: It is run by means of double-clicking the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that it is the `R` executable and not the `Rscript` executable that was run. You can verify this by using a terminal:

```
R  /home/path/to/file/helloworld.R         # produces above error
Rscript /home/path/to/file/helloworld.R    # should work
/home/path/to/file/helloworld.R            # should work if file is executable
```

Most likely your window manager or desktop environment has `.R` files associated with the `R` executable and therefore starts `R` when you doulbe click such a file. How to change that depends on the window manager or desktop environment in use.

Comment: I had the same issue but the executable file doesn''t run even if I choose the right app. My screen (black screen) close prompt(like 1 sec) and I can't figure it out why. I work on windows.

Comment: @MaryNastase I am not a (regular) Windows user myself. It is probably best to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

**You're not running RScript, you're running R, So ask R to tell you to run a file:**

```
$  R --help

Usage: R [options] [< infile] [> outfile]
   or: R CMD command [arguments]

Options:
  --args                Skip the rest of the command line
  -f FILE, --file=FILE  Take input from 'FILE'
  -e EXPR               Execute 'EXPR' and exit
```

**So try it this way:**

```
R -f helloworld.R
```

The question is, why is your `Rscript` executable bugged and pointing to `R`?

Comment: That's not how `Rscript` works on my system (version 3.5, 3.6 and dev on Linux). Why does `Rscript --help` show the output from `R --help`?

Comment: Oh, that's it.  So the problem behind the problem is: Rscript is just default points to R.  The next question becomes: "Why is R installed but Rscript is not installed?"

Comment: Which OS and which R version do you use? How did you install R?

Comment: macOS Mojave, R version 3.3.2 installed with 'brew install r'.  What had happened is my /usr/local/bin/Rscript got root permissions because I was fooling around with it. and after a new install it got bugged, so then Rscript defaults to `R`.  What I did was `rm /usr/local/bin/Rscript` and then do a fresh install and now it works as you say.